# Pass Django Form to js

Tags: javascript, django

I am new to django and I want to write an easy Django application with Django 2.3 and Python 3.7.

I am using in my view.py (if more of my code is needed, I can provide it):

```
 context["form"] = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
 return render(request, "myhtml.html", context)
```

My forms.py also looks very simple:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField()
  address = forms.CharField()
```

I want to build in my application a button in which the form appears, but I do not want to hide the form by display: none;

Is it possible to give the form over in a format that I can use JavaScript to build the form or do I always need to build the form in HTML and manipulate it afterwards with JS? Is it reasonable to return the Form as JSON.Response or does Django always return the Forms as HTML strings and not JS elements?

Comment: Why are you against using `display:none`? The simplest in js would be to toggle that display when you click a button. Note that client side javascript could care less what language or framework is used server side

Comment: I would do it, if it is the most reasonable way, but I would like to add around 50 Select Fields, which would be loaded on the side, so I thought it would be more efficient to do it dynamically in JS.

Comment: Possibly but if you are new to both then just hiding and showing is simplest.

Comment: But what would be the other way?